# Cannot open assembly "path":no such file or directory -- Monogame default game not running?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna, monogame

I've been working in monogame for only a little bit, and I've successfully made the game of fifteen and a few other smaller projects. However, after doing a small routine update to the framework and beginning a new project, the default monogame cross-platform desktop app won't work!

It's throwing an error message that says that there's no .exe file in the Debug folder, which is strange because my other projects have had that in the past with no extra steps.

```
Cannot open assembly '/Users/graemetmcdonough/Projects/help/help/bin/DesktopGL/Any CPU/Debug/help.Desktop.exe': No such file or directory.
```

I don't have any virus protection software turned on, and I haven't changed anything. I've looked all over and this doesn't seem to be an issue previously experienced.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BgXW.jpg

general settings ^^

I expect that I'm making some silly mistake, and that it's very easily solvable, but it's killing me in the meantime!

Comment: Please look for the executable file under `/Users/graemetmcdonough/Projects/help/help/bin/` It is possible the target is no longer Any CPU in The OSX environment.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that your directory (the location where the debug is saved) has changed in the meantime, it's worth comparing your directory paths in the error message and the actual directory path where it's currently located, and see if there's a notable difference.

Comment: Okay! I took a look. The way I got it to work is if I went into the help.csproj file instead of the help.sln. I ran that and it worked! Then, when I went back to try and see what was different from the .sln file, it turned out that it worked again. I've no idea what would cause it to do that, but I appreciate your help!

Comment: If anyone has any ideas as to why that might be, just let me know!

Comment: I'm not sure what the cause of that difference makes, It might be worth checking in the .sln and see if the Solution Configuration (usually next to your 'play button') is set on Debug, instead of Release. But at least I'm glad that you've found a solution yourself.